# Can't connect using mysqli_connect, but mysql_connect works..?

Tags: php, mysql

I got the credentials for connecting to MySQL directly from my hosting provider (1and1). However, when I try to connect with the following code:

```
$db_hostname = 'localhost/tmp/mysql5.sock';
$db_database = 'db543062602';
$db_username = '***********';
$db_password = '***********';

$dbc = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database)
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
?>
```

ERROR:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   'localhost/tmp/mysql5.sock' (1) in /homepages/... ... ... /purge.php
>   on line 10 Error connecting to MySQL server

The credentials are all the same. In fact, it works when connecting using mysql_connect(), but it doesn't want to work with mysql_connect()! Any thoughts on what could be causing the problem?

Comment: `$db_hostname` is just `localhost` is it not?

Comment: 1and1 recommended using the one provided, but I tried it without the '/tmp/...' as well. I also tried using the IP address to no avail.

Comment: hostname should either be a hostname (`example.com`) or an IP address.

Comment: Interestingly... I copied the current hostname directly from the 1and1 'MySQL Database Set Up and Configuration' page.

Comment: Could you try $dbc = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database); Just to see if it doesn't connect either?

Comment: Same issue. I feel like they may have listed my info wrong..?

Comment: You do know that the one I gave you won't work with procedural style connections right? Try if($dbc->connect_errno) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $dbc->connect_error); }

Comment: Try setting $db_hostname to simply 'localhost` . IN theory that should attempt to use the best possible mechanism to connect to the database (whether through socket or pipe)

Comment: Tried it ice cub. and tried that too Michael.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either you have misinterpreted the instructions from 1&1, or else they made a mistake.

Read the manual page for [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). It shows that the first argument should be the hostname, either by name or IP. Do not include the socket in that argument.

You can optionally specify the socket file as the *sixth* argument.

```
/* WRONG */
mysqli_connect('localhost/tmp/mysql5.sock', ... );

/* WRONG */
mysqli_connect('localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock', ... );

/* RIGHT */
mysqli_connect('localhost', $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, null, '/tmp/mysql5.sock');
```

Also, I wonder why they even require you to specify the socket. They should define a default in the host's php.ini file, so you don't have to. Unless perhaps they're running multiple instances of mysqld on the same host.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much Bill! I wonder why they told me that was my hostname? Oh well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at [mysqli_connect()'s manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

> mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string **$host** = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string **$socket** = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )

... and:

> **host**
>
> Can be either a **host name** or an **IP address**. Passing the NULL value or
> the string "localhost" to this parameter, the local host is assumed.
> When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP protocol.
>
> **socket**
>
> Specifies the socket or named pipe that should be used.

I admit the manual page could use an example but there's no trace of the syntax you're trying out.

---

Please remember that *mysqli* is **a different extension** than the legacy *mysql* one:

> resource mysql_connect ([ string **$server** = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )

... where:

> **server**
>
> The MySQL server. It can also include a port number. e.g. "hostname:port" or a path to a local socket e.g. ":/path/to/socket" for the localhost.

Comment: With all due respect, I must disagree. If you look under the examples provided by the documentation (specifically the procedural style example), you will see that my syntax matches up perfectly.

Comment: I might be overlooking something but I can't see any example with local sockets or where argument #1 is anything else than a host name or IP address :-?

Comment: I must apologize. I didn't realize that you meant not including the socket in the first parameter. My mistake. I'll give you an upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your hostname should be:

```
localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock
```

and not:

`localhost/tmp/mysql5.sock`

[Reference](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/databases-c85147/mysql-database-c37730/connect-to-a-mysql5-database-on-a-managed-server-a752513.html)

Or it seems there's also [alternative method](http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/databases-c85147/mysql-database-c37730/mysql-database-connection-credentials-a748746.html) to find your host so you should try get data from your panel.

Comment: @bboysupaman You can also look at http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/databases-c85147/mysql-database-c37730/mysql-database-connection-credentials-a748746.html

Comment: I'll take a look now. This is maddening. Lol.

Comment: The information in that panel matches what I'm putting in.

Comment: So you need to simply contact with 1&1 support. That will be probably the best solution

Answer (score 0):

please just add 
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql5.sock;
this line in php.ini at root of your server .